# Время движения для змейки С++

Tags: c++, таймер

Вот я написал:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

char a[100][100];
//Початкові координати
int sx = 15, sy = 10;
//Напрям
int direct; 

void view();
void border();

//Напрямок
int direction(int direct) {
    if (direct == 0) return sy--;
    if (direct == 1) return sx++;
    if (direct == 2) return sy++;
    if (direct == 3) return sx--;
}

int main(){

    while (getch() != 27) {

        border();
        Sleep(500);
        switch (getch()) {
            case 72: direct = 0; break; //вгору
            case 77: direct = 1; break; //вправо
            case 80: direct = 2; break; //вниз
            case 75: direct = 3; break; //вліво
        }

        direction(direct);

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 60; j++) {
                a[sy][sx] = '0';
                if (sy >= 19 || sy <= 0 || sx >= 59 || sx <= 0) goto gameover;

            }

        system("cls");
        view();

    }

    gameover:
    cout << "Game over..." << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

//Границі поля
void border() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 60; j++) {
            a[i][j] = ' ';
            a[0][j] = '#';
            a[i][0] = '#';
            a[19][j] = '#';
            a[i][59] = '#';
        }
}
//Малює поле
void view() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 60; j++) {
            cout << a[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Вопрос: Мне не понятен момент с временем, по-этому у меня здесь не правильно фурычит. Помогите пожалуйста принять меры, чтобы при проходе каждой секунды элемент "0" сдвигался в нужном направлении.

Comment: Можно в отдельном потоке запустить...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так не получится. 
Ты ожидаешь ввод - останавливая цикл, а вовремя  Sleep(500); и ввод работать не будут.

Выход: нужен таймер, который будет проверятся в цикле, и когда пройдет секунда сдвинет "0" в указанном направлении. А если была нажата клавиша(изменено направление), то таймер сбрасываться.  А также ожидание ввода, которое не останавливает цикл(перехват события, другой поток.... ).

Comment: да я то знаю, а вот с помощью чего мне это сделать?

Comment: @goodalien1125 насколько я знаю нормального таймер в плюсах нет, гуглится только таймер на который нужно кода писать больше чем у тебя ушло на змейку...  https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms687008(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: это ещё не вся змейка)) Спасибо и на том..

Comment: При вводе достаточно использовать не ожидающую `kbhit()` из того же `conio.h`. Просто не ждем нажатия, а проверяем, есть ли оно, и читаем только тогда, когда там что-то есть...

Comment: @Harry, подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно воплотить?

Comment: @goodalien1125, так смотрите мой ответ - там учтен комментарий Harry

Comment: @sba, мне просто не все ясно там..

Comment: В основном цикле. Я бы делал примерно так - небольшая задержка и проверка, если нажато - `getch()` и обработка. Если не нажато - то пока не наберется задержек на секунду. Но секунда - это будет очень тормознутая змейка :)

Answer (score 3):

Я привожу здесь простой ответ который решает поставленную задачу без излишних усложнений. То-есть без таймеров, много-поточности и асинхронности.

В общем случае мы имеем игровой цикл (while), который тикает так быстро как только может процессор. Следует учесть что на разных процессорах скорость будет разной, а по хорошему хотелось бы иметь одинаковую скорость на любом процессоре. Как же можно организовать движение змейки? Очевидно, есть два решения - либо на каждом тике сдвигать змейку на очень небольшое расстояние (что в терминологии использования текстового режима слегка неуместно), либо делать это не на каждом тике. Собственно ниже будет представлен пример как это делать не на каждом тике.

Идея состоит в том чтобы на каждой итерации игрового цикла расчитывать время которое прошло с момента предыдущего обновления размещения змейки на игровом поле. То-есть если мы хотим сдвигать змейку на одну позицию ровно каждую секунду, то нам необходимо *пропустить* столько итераций игрового цикла что соответствуют этому интервалу времени.

Следует перед основным циклом сохранить текущее время, и на каждой итерации замерять дельту - разницу между текущим временем и временем сохраненным ранее. Если дельта больше или равна необходимому интервалу (1 секунде) производим необходимые действия.

```
auto lastUpdate = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
char ch = 0;
while (ch != 27) {
  auto now(std::chrono::steady_clock::now());
  auto dt = now - lastUpdate;
  if (dt >= std::chrono::seconds(1)) {
    lastUpdate = now;
    // здесь производим необходимые действия - тоесть сдвигаем змейку на 1 позициию
  }

  if (kbhit()) {
    // обработка ввода
    ch = getch();
  }
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
}
```

Comment: Почему бы тогда не использовать sleep()?

Comment: @goodalien1125, можете использовать, предположу, привычную Вам `Sleep()`. Уже работающий Ваш пример следует просто дополнить 4-5 строками кода - вычисляющими дельту (прошедшее время) любым удобным способом. Я всего лишь привел пример с использованием стандарта C++11.

Comment: а что скажете по поводу того, что очень туго идет управление змейкой? Я имею ввиду, что клавиши через раз понимают, что я жму на них..

Comment: Возьмите за скелет основного цикла именно код из примера - управление должно стать гладким. Ваши 500 мс заметны на глаз, 10 мс незаметны и добавят гладкости.

Comment: да нет! Вишка в том, что если даже ставлю sleep(30-150), то змейка двигается очень быстро и не успевает захватить мой тык на клавишу..